# Vector categorization

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to represent an huge vector in terms of pre-defined bins and do 1-k encoding. For example, if my vector is

```
1.101

3.45

8

9.91

2.47

5.5

6.8
```

and I have four bins

- Bin 1: (0 - 2.5), and its 1-k encoding `1 0 0 0`
- Bin 2: (2.51 - 5) and its 1-k encoding `0 1 0 0`
- Bin 3: (5.01 - 7.5) and its 1-k encoding `0 0 1 0`
- Bin 4 : (7.51 - 10) and its 1-k encoding `0 0 0 1`

I want to build a new matrix (7x4) which represents the vector in the following way:

```
1.101 --> 1 0 0 0

3.45  --> 0 1 0 0

8     --> 0 0 0 1

9.91  --> 0 0 0 1

2.47  --> 1 0 0 0

5.5   --> 0 0 1 0

6.8   --> 0 0 1 0
```

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to use [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) to do a histogram count, but instead of getting the histogram, you want the find the actual **bin** the value belonged to.  You need the third output of `histcounts` for that. You also need to make sure that the bin edges vary from 0 to 10 in steps of 2.5.   Once you have this, simply create a `sparse` matrix where for the nonzero entries, the rows varies from 1 up to as many values as you have in your vector and the columns are directly using the third output of `histcounts`.  You'll also want to convert to `full` when you're done.

```
vec = [1.101; 3.45; 8; 9.91; 2.47; 5.5; 6.8]; %// Your example

[~,~,bin] = histcounts(vec, 0:2.5:10); %// Find which bin each value belongs to

%// Compute the matrix
out = full(sparse((1:numel(vec)).', bin, 1));
```

---

We get:

```
out =

     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0
```